# Morris js chart - changing settings dynamically

Tags: morris.js

Is it possible to update a Morris chart dynamically? I know `setData()` will update the data, but I want to update the settings. Namely, the user being able to select if a bar chart is stacked or not.

I have tried:

```
bChart.stacked = true;
bChart.setData(response);
```

... because `setData()` will redraw. I also tried `bChart.redraw();`. There was no change.

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 5):

You were 90% there. You would need to set `bChart.options.stacked` to `true;` then do `bChart.redraw();`.

Therefore, the code for toggling stacked bars is the following (if you are using jQuery):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#stacked').on('change', function() {
        bChart.options.stacked = $(this).is(':checked');
        bChart.redraw();
    });
});
```

Providing that the checkbox toggling this option has a `#stacked` ID.

[See this working JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uqLp75h1/3/)